# None of [Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64', name='index')] are in the [index]

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I got this error while I am trying to run my sequential keras model.

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['category'] = data['category'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
df['title'] = data['title'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
df['description'] = data['description']

x = df.description
y = df.category

SEED = 2000
x_train, x_validation_and_test, y_train, y_validation_and_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.02, random_state=SEED)
x_validation, x_test, y_validation, y_test = train_test_split(x_validation_and_test, y_validation_and_test, test_size=.5, random_state=SEED)
```

And my model:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=batch_generator(x_train_tfidf, y_train, 32),
                        epochs=5, validation_data=(x_validation_tfidf, y_validation),
                        steps_per_epoch=x_train_tfidf.shape[0]/32)
```

I got this arror at:

```
steps_per_epoch=x_train_tfidf.shape[0]/32
```

df.info

> ```
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> Int64Index: 994 entries, 0 to 1092
> Data columns (total 3 columns):
> category       994 non-null int32
> title          994 non-null int32
> description    994 non-null object
> dtypes: int32(2), object(1)
> memory usage: 23.3+ KB
> ```

df.index

> ```
> Int64Index([   0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    6,    7,    8,   10,   11,
>             ...
>             1083, 1084, 1085, 1086, 1087, 1088, 1089, 1090, 1091, 1092],
>            dtyp
> ```

e='int64', name='index', length=994)

EDIT:
I don't understand if it's from slicing the data not properly or indexing is wrong.

Added more code:

```
tvec1 = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=100000,ngram_range=(1, 3))
tvec1.fit(x_train)

x_train_tfidf = tvec1.transform(x_train)
x_validation_tfidf = tvec1.transform(x_validation).toarray()

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(x_train_tfidf, y_train)

clf.score(x_validation_tfidf, y_validation)
clf.score(x_train_tfidf, y_train)

seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
```

Here is my batch_generator:

```
def batch_generator(X_data, y_data, batch_size):
    samples_per_epoch = X_data.shape[0]
    number_of_batches = samples_per_epoch/batch_size
    counter=0
    index = np.arange(np.shape(y_data)[0])
    while 1:
        index_batch = index[batch_size*counter:batch_size*(counter+1)]
        X_batch = X_data[index_batch,:].toarray()
        y_batch = y_data[y_data.index[index_batch]]
        counter += 1
        yield X_batch,y_batch
        if (counter > number_of_batches):
            counter=0
```

Comment: could you report batch_generator

Comment: in batch_generator, define X_batch and y_batch in this way... X_batch = X_data.values[index_batch,:] and y_batch = y_data.values[index_batch]

Comment: @MarcoCerliani, i replaced that lines with the ones you wrote but got an AttributeError: values not found

Comment: X_data is a dataframe, y_data is a dataframe/series or a numpy array?

Comment: X_data is csr_matrix and y_data is series

Comment: ok try X_batch = X_data[index_batch,:].toarray() and y_batch = y_data.values[index_batch] and when you define x_validation_tfidf remove to_array

Comment: unfortunately result is same

Comment: @Melike. based on what you've said, the problem code should be the line `y_batch = y_data[y_data.index[index_batch]]` since it is the only one that could raise this data frame error. What @Marco suggested should have caused this error to stop in this case. Please check for any `.pyc` or `.cache` files and remove them. It may be that your code changes are not being recompiled or recached. I should note that I have been unable to reproduce this error despite my best efforts and I see nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Maybe there is a problem in my data. None of the solutions seems working.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem may be that your dataframe has indexes with some values missing. That is, the length is 994 but you have indexes up to 1092 so some rows are left out. This is probably causing `batch_generator` to fail when indexing the dataframe.

So, before all of your provided code, try using:

```py
data.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: unfortunately i got the same error again. i tried the run the code with similar dataset and got a similar error (KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]").

Comment: @Melike, could you try returning `y_batch.values` instead of `y_batch` inside of `batch_generator`?

Comment: it didn't change anything